# Google search form turns up mostly white page

Tags: html, forms, google-search

I've got this super simple search form on my home page:

```
<form method="get" action="https://google.ca">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="q" autofocus>
</form>
```

When I type into it and press enter, it takes me to Google like I want, but then it just hangs on this white page. Happens in Chrome, Firefox, and Edge.

How can I make a form that successfully searches Google?

[image]

Comment: I'm thinking that you may have a corrupted "History" data file...
Try moving the following file "History". To locate it do this...

Comment: Clear the cache and the cookies from websites that cause problems.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?q=bacon   i think Your Url is not correct format

Comment: @IvinRaj I tried 3 different browsers. Caches and histories aren't cross-browser.

Comment: @IvinRaj When I click that, it exhibits the same behaviour. White page. But if you press enter, it submits. Is there a trick to getting it to submit immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have entered a incorrect URL Address `https://www.google.co.in/?q=bacon`

You can try this this one:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.ca/search?">
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="q" autofocus>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh what the heck...how did I not notice I missed the `/search`? Thank you!